# Can I add protocol conformance to `UnsignedInteger` via extensions on those protocols?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have 2 protocols, `JSONStringConvertible` and `JSONSerializable`. I want Int, Int64, UInt32, etc. to all conform to these protocols.

I wrote this code

```
public extension JSONSerializable where Self:Integer, Self:JSONStringConvertible
{
    var jsonObject: JSONStringConvertible { return self }
}
public extension JSONStringConvertible where Self:Integer
{
    var jsonString: String { return "" }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I have to do this:

```
extension Int : JSONStringConvertible, JSONSerializable
{
    public var jsonObject: JSONStringConvertible { return self }
    public var jsonString: String { return String( self ) }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll have to add the conformance separately for each `UnsignedInteger` type you're interested in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what you have written here:

```
//                                           vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
public extension JSONStringConvertible where Self:UnsignedInteger
```

The extension only applies to unsigned integers! Is `Int` an unsigned integer? No! `Int` is a signed integer while `UInt` is unsigned.

So just change `Unsigned` to `Signed` and then make extensions on `Int`, `Int64`, `Int32` etc. e.g.

```
extension Int: JSONStringConvertible, JSONSerializable {}
extension Int32: JSONStringConvertible, JSONSerializable {}
extension Int64: JSONStringConvertible, JSONSerializable {}
```

Also, you would have to add other protocol extensions where `Self:UnsignedInteger`, so all your protocol extensions will look like this:

```
extension JSONSerializable where Self:SignedInteger, Self:JSONStringConvertible
{
    var jsonObject: JSONStringConvertible { return self }
}
extension JSONStringConvertible where Self:SignedInteger
{
    var jsonString: String { return "" }
}

extension JSONSerializable where Self:UnsignedInteger, Self:JSONStringConvertible
{
    var jsonObject: JSONStringConvertible { return self }
}
extension JSONStringConvertible where Self:UnsignedInteger
{
    var jsonString: String { return "" }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My code actually has extensions as you have written--I just didn't post them all... I've fixed my question.

Comment: This is the correct answer--although you can remove the initial part about SignedInt/UnsignedInt. Thanks!